# Adding extra characters to a list of email adresses in tsql

Tags: string, t-sql, function

I have an output text file with millions of email addresses in them. I need an sql function to take each each email address as input and format it to add the `'` and `',` characters to them. So as an example:

Input is:

```
joe.bloggs@test.com
dan.bloggs@test.com
```

Expected Output:

```
'joe.bloggs@test.com',
'dan.bloggs@test.com',
```

Comment: where is your "and" in output

Answer (score 0):

```
select ''''+replace('joe.bloggs@test.com dan.bloggs@test.com', ' ', ''', ''')+''''
```

Answer (score 0):

So to answer one of my junior devs under my login - a quick solution:

SELECT distinct(',''' + Email + '''')
FROM [Table]